# Can I use TOR for chat or e-mail with China?

Tags: help

Sirs, Forgive me but I'm an unsophisticated end user unlike all the experts here.  I live in the USA.  I have a friend in China.  The "Great Wall" of China blocks all our attempts to communicate; e-mail, chat, if it's online you name it.  We only can communicate through an expensive proprietary chat service.  *****Can I use TOR to e-mail and/or chat with my friend in China?*****  How do I do it?  I assume my friend in China has to sign up too.  Is TOR available with instructions in Chinese?  I would be most grateful for any assistance.  If it works, I will be more than happy to donate to TOR.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is possible to use Tor to evade such censorship, but using some random encrypted chat service would be much easier. Actually something like [Signal](https://signal.org/android/apk/) or [Zom](https://zom.im/) might just work fine (or not, depending on a lot of things) for you and your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Using Tor in China is very difficult. The Tor Project website itself is blocked, so your friend cannot even download the Tor Browser directly. Tor protocol is blocked. All the public Tor bridges are blocked.

So to get Tor to work from China, you would need to download the Tor Browser needed by your friend and reupload it to a server somewhere your friend can get at it. Tor with meek, or Tor with a private unlisted bridge that you set up yourself, MAY then work in China.

Comment: IPv6 bridges are also usable in China.